# If $(Y,T)$ is a connected minimal system with a symbolic extension of linear word complexity, is $(Y,T)$ equicontinuous?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, symbolic-dynamics

Let $(Y,S)$ be a minimal topological dynamical system such that $Y$ is **connected**. A simple example of a system like this is an irrational rotation of the circle, and it is known that Sturmian sequences are symbolic extension of these systems and that have linear word complexity function. More generally, any irrational torus rotation has a symbolic extension of linear complexity (actually, a substitutive subshift).

**My question is about the converse: if $\pi:(X,T) \to (Y,T)$ is a factor map such that $(X,T)$ is a minimal linear-complexity subshift and $Y$ connected, then is $(Y,S)$ equicontinuous?**

I think that the low complexity of $(X,T)$ and the connectedness hypothesis on $Y$ forces $(Y,T)$ to be of "low complexity" as well; maybe, equicontinuous.

Comment: Did you mean to also say $Y$ is connected in the statement of your question?

Comment: @DanRust Yes! I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: By linear complexity, do you mean liminf or limsup?

Comment: I was thinking in lim sup:
$$ p(n) \leq Cn,\quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$
But a counterexample with
$$ \liminf_{n\to\infty}p(n)/n < +\infty $$
it is also interesting for me.